# Quantum Particle in a Fractal Box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, mathematical-physics, differential-equations, fractals

I was thinking about particle in a 2D box the other day, and I realize that it shapes actually affect its energy and wavefunction. Therefore I thought to myself, what if a particle is inside a fractal box (i.e., in Koch snowflake), how would the wavefunction look like, and how different it would be from the usual particle in a box.

---

I guess that it would be quite different considering the complex shape of the boundary. I also admit, I have no idea how to write the mathematical expression of the boundary condition.

Comment: You might find this paper helpfull https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/35/48/306

Comment: Have a look on [this](https://tddft.org/bmg/files/papers/5329275.pdf) on this Bachelor thesis. There is also a book, which might be of interest: *Fractional Quantum Mechanics. Nick Laskin. World Scientific.*

Comment: Thank you @JasonFunderberker, this one looks very promising